# Android SDK 2.0.1

Tags: android, sdk

Can any one knows, how i can get android SDK **2.0.1**, i have seen developer.android.com but there is not avaiable the Android version 2.0.1.

However Available in **Older versions** What is that mean ? the version is obsolete ???

Kindly give me the authentic answer

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You must download the latest version. During setup, you can choose which versions of the SDK to download and install, going right back to version 1.

Comment: But 2.0.1 does not appear in the list of old SDK versions.

Answer (score 1):

I think 2.0.1 has been "deprecated" as there is (and will never be) any devices that runs it. The only one was Droid/Milestone and it has been updated to 2.1/2.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you need older version just to develop for earlier versions of API then get newest SDK version. 
After that you can install only components you like and select them when creating the project.

See documentation: http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first install ADT plugin in eclipse.Follow the steps given below to do the same

http://developer.android.com/intl/de/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

Once you are done open ADT Plugin from eclipse. You need to download the SDK's that you require from this plugin directly

You can see the list of sdk's in "Available Packages" option something similar to the screenshot shown in this page

http://developer.android.com/intl/de/sdk/installing.html#components

Just select the SDK accept the terms and conditions. Your download should start

Comment: But 2.0.1 is not in that list.

Comment: Hmmm... I am not sure y. I already have 2.0.1 installed(i did it long back). The developer site still displays 2.0.1 in older versions. So i think it should be there http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.0.1.html

Comment: Check it on the list of Installed and Available Packages. In case ur machine has 2.0.1 already it wont show up there